# Finding autocorrelation coefficients given PSD values at 2 frequencies

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, signal-processing, spectral-analysis, fourier-transform

Assuming that $S_X(w)$ denotes powers spectral density function at
frequency $w$, we are given
$$S_X\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=10+3\sqrt{2},\quad
S_X\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=11+3\sqrt{3}.$$ We also know that the
autocorrelation function $R_X$ has the properties $R_X(0) = 10$ and
$R_X(m) = 0$ for $|m|\geq 3$. What is the value of $\frac{R_X(1)}{R_X(2)} $?

**An attempt:** It is known that $\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}R_X(m) = E^2\{X\}$. Since $R_X$ is assumed to be $0$ for large $m$, we immediately conclude that $E^2\{X\}=0$.

On the other hand the autocorrelation can be obtained from $S_X$ by applying the inverse Fourier transform.
This would lead to
$$ R_X(1) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} S_X(f) e^{2i\pi f }\,\mathrm d\!f$$
$$ R_X(2) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} S_X(f) e^{4i\pi f }\,\mathrm d\!f$$
but calculating these integrals look formidable as is. Maybe we can use our information on $E^2\{X\}$?
Anyhow, I have no clue on how to continue. Your help is greatly appreciated!

(If it's any help, the solution manual says $\frac{R_X(1)}{R_X(2)}=3$, but it doesn't explain how or why.)

Comment: According to the properties of autocorrelation function, $R_X(0)\geq |R_X(k)|$ for all $k$, so how is it $0$?

Comment: My bad. It's $R_X(0) = 10$. I made a typo. Do you think I have to repost the question with the correction? I guess a lot of the viewers may have moved on because the problem couldn't be solved because of the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are several things to assume further in the question. The given equations are probably for $\omega=\pi/4$ and $\omega=\pi/6$, instead of $f=\pi/4$ and $f=\pi/6$ for the ease of calculations. $S_x(\omega)$ is another and common way of writing PSDs, especially when the given input series is *discrete* (although it's not stated explicitly in the question). Therefore, I'm going to take the DTFT of the discrete autocorrelation series to obtain the PSD:

$$S_x(\omega)=\sum_{k=-3}^3 R_x(k)e^{-jwk}=R_x(0)+2R_x(1)\cos (\omega)+2R_x(2)\cos (2\omega)+2R_x(3)\cos(3\omega)$$

And, substituting frequencies in the given equations, we have:
$$S_x(\pi/4)=10+R_x(1)\sqrt 2-R_x(3)\sqrt 2=10+3\sqrt 2$$
$$S_x(\pi/6)=10+R_x(1)\sqrt 3+R_x(2)=11+3\sqrt 3$$

It's not possible to solve this uniquely. So, another assumption of mine is  $R_x(3)=0$, i.e. some another typo in the question statement that $R_x(k)=0$ for $|k|\geq 3$ instead of $|k|>3$, using these equations, we'll find that $R_x(1)=3,R_x(2)=1$, so the answer would be correct.

**Notes on the literature difference:**
Many sources in the time-series literature defines the autocorrelation function a bit differently than the signal processing literature. Here, I believe it's assumed that $R_x(k)=E[x_nx_{n-k}]$, instead of $\rho(k)=\operatorname{cov}(x_n,x_{n-k})/\operatorname{var}(x_n)$.

**Notes to the OP:**
I've made a lot of assumptions to *correct* the question statement, which couldn't be possible if I weren't quite familiar with the topic. So, either the question statement has full of errors in it, or you mistyped a lot of things. This highly decreases the chance of someone answering your question, so I advise you to do your best while asking questions.

Comment: Many thanks for the insightful solution and corrections. You were absolutely right about the typos, I should have double-checked the details. Also this problem Indeed comes from signal processing, your assumption on $R$ is also correct.

Comment: I just got a small question, if you humor me. Have you also assumed that $R_x(m) = R_x(-m)$? According to my textbook, this is valid for stationary processes, is it also valid here in your opinion?

Comment: Yes, I assumed that as well.